# Update list item not retuning full item properties

Tags: web-services, attachments, updatelistitems

I'm using SharePoint web services to update items by calling the UpdateListItems method, and the response is not providing me the attachment data of the item correctly as other services does, like GetListItems.

Is there a way to tell the UpdateListItems service in the soap message, to return the full item properties as a result of the service?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. You will need to call GetListItems or [GetAttachmentCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getattachmentcollection%28v=office.12%29.aspx) afterwards.

Comment: Agree.. I didn't find any alternatives